# Read VCFCard from QR Code?

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I want to ask if is it possible to read VCF Card as CNContact data like givenName, familyName...

This is my QR Code Scanner output function

```
  func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
        messageLabel.text = "No QR/barcode is detected"
        return
    }


    let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

    if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
        let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

        if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
            messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
        }
    }
}
```

printed output

```
"
<AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject: 0x17022d1e0, type="org.iso.QRCode", bounds={ 0.3,0.4 0.1x0.3 }>corners { 0.3,0.7 0.5,0.7 0.5,0.4 0.3,0.4 }, time 93849323998125, stringValue "BEGIN:VCARD

VERSION:3.0

PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//iPhone OS 10.2//EN

N:Hank;Patrick;;;

FN: Patrick  Hank 

EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=HOME;type=pref:patrick.hank01@gmail.com

TEL;type=IPHONE;type=CELL;type=VOICE;type=pref:0911311911

END:VCARD

"
```

Comment: Your code has no `print`s, so I'm not sure what your "printed output" represents. But you may try with `CNContactVCardSerialization`.

Comment: I added under MessageLabel.text...etc. ... print(metadataObj).. trying but don't know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot test with your QR Code, but this would be some help:

```
        if
            let metadataString = metadataObj.stringValue,
            let data = metadataString.data(using: .utf8)
        {
            do {
                let contacts = try CNContactVCardSerialization.contacts(with: data)
                print(contacts)
                //Use `contacts` as you like
                if let contact = contacts.first {
                    print(contact.givenName)
                    //...
                }
                //...
            } catch {
                //Unreadable as CNContact
                print(error)
                //...
            }
        } else {
            //May never happen...
        }
```

Comment: and how can I get for example givenName?

Comment: @patrikbelis, please check the [reference of `CNContact`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts/cncontact), `givenName` is just a property of a `CNContact` instance...

Comment: I mean when i scan vcfCard as QR code... And How can I get givenName throught that serialization?

Comment: @patrikbelis, in my code above, `contact` is a `CNContact` instance.

Comment: I cant use contact.givenName

Comment: @patrikbelis, sorry, I was too short. `contact` is an Array of `CNContact`. (The name should be `contacts`...). I'll update my answer.